# Edit document content in postProcessor

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, itext

I want to edit table stlyes eg color of header which is add from primefaces `dataTable` when it is export by `dataExport` to pdf.

I do not see in `com.lowagie.text.Document` (argument of `postProcessMethod`) method which return content of pdf document.

I need do this in `preProcessMethod`? If yes then how to? There also is the same object in the argument.

Comment: As soon as you have a PDF document, it does not contain table headers and contents anymore, merely glyphs positioned somewhere on the page. Thus, you should do anything requiring you to identify parts of the content before you have it in PDF.

Comment: Ok. But when and where I can do this? There is any listener interface for this or something else? In `dataExport` tag I have only preProcess and postProcess values to manipulate the document.

Comment: Hello, I'm the lowagie you're referring to. I don't recognize dataTable or dataExport, nor do I recognize a method named postProcessMethod. The fact that you refer to my name also means that you're using a version of iText that hasn't been supported for three years: http://lowagie.com/itext2 Moreover when I go to primefaces.org, I see that Primefaces is released under the Apache License which is incompatible with the iText license. There is however some info about the license here: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24932

Comment: Thank you for the information. Of course, when I use iText to commercial product I will do this on rules from the iText license.